# Anyone know how to customize the servlet port for an embedded JBoss container using Maven Cargo?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, cargo, maven-cargo

I"m using Maven 3.0.3 with the Cargo 1.3.3 plugin.  I'm trying to configure an embedded JBoss 7.1 container.  I would like to customize the port on which JBoss listens for requests, normally 8080.  However, I can't seem to customize it, using the "cargo.servlet.port" property in the configuration section.  Below is my configuration

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <home>${project.build.directory}/jboss-${jboss.version}/container</home>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>${jboss.servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                        </properties>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>jboss${jboss.major}x</containerId>
                            <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip</url>
                                <downloadDir>${project.basedir}/downloads</downloadDir>
                                <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                            </zipUrlInstaller>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/jboss${jboss.major}x.log</output>
                            <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                        </container>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <location>target/${project.artifactId}.${project.packaging}</location>
                                <pingURL>http://localhost:${jboss.servlet.port}/${project.artifactId}</pingURL>
                                <pingTimeout>60000</pingTimeout>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-container</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-container</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Here is the bind exception I get in the application server log (I already have a JBoss instance running on port 8080).

```
16:45:41,913 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
16:45:42,010 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]

16:45:42,025 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
    ... 5 more
```

The reason I like the Cargo plugin is it allows me to use my own JBoss standalone.xml configuration, but am open to alternatives to Cargo, provided I can customize my config.  Thanks for any guidance, - Dave

Comment: Have you looked at the jboss-as-maven-plugin? https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You seemingly just have a small bug in your configuration. The properties are part of the Cargo configuration, which is a child/property of the plugin configuration, so in fact, you have to put a configuration tag inside a configuration tag. Here's mine (partly):

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <container>
          <!-- Add your container here, we use a custom one -->
        </container>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <cargo.servlet.port>5556</cargo.servlet.port>
            <!-- other properties -->
          </properties>
          <configfiles combine.children="append">
            <!-- here we add our configuration files -->
            <configfile>
              <!-- Expect configfiles to be filtered and gathered in 
                target/jboss71x (in the respective subdirectories) -->
              <file>${project.build.directory}/cargo/jboss71x</file>
            </configfile>
          </configfiles>
        </configuration>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: The configuration/configuration still applies. This is an old post, now days we have chat-gpt. but it could not give the correct answer.
Thank you for providing this answer 11 years ago :)